# Passing a ViewBag/ViewData on each page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, design-patterns

I have a very large asp.NET MVC application and I'm looking for the most efficient way of accomplishing adding a help document to each view. So in essence,I have added a partial view inside of the layout; that gets called on every page, that invokes a helper method to get return a string and the string is just the URL of the help docs for that specific page.

**This is One approach:**

```
{Key: "User_Management",      Value: "/Account/User/List"},
{Key: "User_Management_Edit", Value: "/Account/User/Edit"}
```

The Key would be what i'm looking for as part of the URL and the value would be the returned URL string.
So if the URL is `/User/Management/` Then the returned value would be the first of the list, `/Account/User/List`.

**A second approach** could be to store the key`User_Management` directly into the view as a ViewBag or ViewData and then check the value in the helper.

My only concern is that with approach One I would have to maintain the keys to make sure that they match the URL, and with approach Two, i'm wondering if it's inefficient to pass a string as a viewbag on each view.

Would love to hear some alternatives or if anyone has a better idea.

Comment: Does each page have it's own help document URL, or all pages user the same Help URL? How do you lookup `/User/Management/` URL in the list, the corresponding key is: `User_Management`? I recommend concentrating on writing a clear question, have a look at: [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Yes, Each page does have it's own help document URL.
I look up the URL in the list by getting the first part of the URL; `User` in this case, and then I match it to the first part of the key, using each underscore as a separator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative, good or bad...

What about a filter? You could create the below filter and explicitly set help document url on each action. The filter would take care of putting it in the same viewbag key so you didnt have to type it every time and risk typos.

```
public class HelpDocumentActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    string helpDocUrl { get; set; }

    public HelpDocumentActionFilter(string _url)
    {
        helpDocUrl = _url;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        //whatever viewbag key you wanted with an opportunity to hit the DB or transform the argument
        filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.HelpUrl = helpDocUrl;
    }

}
```

usage

```
 [HelpDocumentActionFilter("/help/doc2")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't think of this, could certainly work, Thank you for the idea!